# Showing touch keyboard in custom control for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

We can show/hide touch keyboard for windows store apps using a `Custom AutomationPeer`, but for Windows Phone 8.1 `OnCreateAutomationPeer()` is not invoking on `GotFocus()`.

How can I make it do so? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the focus using the [FocusManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

In general it works like this to remove a focus and thus hide the keyboard:

```
var focusedObject = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement();
if (focusedObject != null)
{
    var root = (Frame)Application.Current.RootVisual;
    // Set Focus to Page to close the keyboard
    if (root != null) root.Focus();
}
```